# Long cascaded MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a query the is linked to four depth tables:

This is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE `TableA` 
(
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ValueA` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `TableA` (`ID`, `ValueA`) 
VALUES (1, 20), (2, 30); 

CREATE TABLE `TableB` 
(
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ValueB` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `TableA_ID` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `TableB` (`ID`, `ValueB`, `TableA_ID`) 
VALUES (1, 40, 2), (2, 60, 1);

CREATE TABLE `TableC` 
(
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ValueC` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `TableB_ID` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `TableC` (`ID`, `ValueC`, `TableB_ID`) 
VALUES (1, 101, 2), (2, 102, 1);

CREATE TABLE `TableD`
(
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ValueD` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `TableC_ID` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `TableD` (`ID`, `ValueD`, `TableC_ID`) 
VALUES (1, 200, 1), (2, 100, 2);

ALTER TABLE `TableA`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

ALTER TABLE `TableB`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `TableB_ak_1` (`TableA_ID`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `TableB_TableA` FOREIGN KEY (`TableA_ID`) REFERENCES `TableA` (`ID`);

ALTER TABLE `TableC`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `TableC_ak_1` (`TableB_ID`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `TableC_TableB` FOREIGN KEY (`TableB_ID`) REFERENCES `TableB` (`ID`);

ALTER TABLE `TableD`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `TableD_ak_1` (`TableC_ID`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `TableD_TableC` FOREIGN KEY (`TableC_ID`) REFERENCES `TableC` (`ID`);
```

They are connected with unique constrains. So basically for every ID in TableD I'll have a value from tableA.

Now, what is the right method for getting this info except for running queries like the following one:

```
mysql> select ValueA from TableA where ID = (select TableA_ID from TableB where ID = (select TableB_ID from TableC where ID = (Select TableC_ID from TableD where ID = 1)));
+--------+
| ValueA |
+--------+
|     20 |
+--------+
```

Comment: Have you considered using `JOIN`?

Comment: No. Just opened the documentation for it. Isn't it for combining data from 2 tables? I have here few "tables of separation". Checking how can JOIN help

Comment: See answers below. My answer has a link to a working demo at SQLFiddle.

Comment: Thank you all. First, it works. Now I'm going to learn about JOIN.
BTW, if I wanted to add another column to TableD that will be automatically populated with that value, should use this JOIN in a trigger?

Comment: I found this blog post to be a really nice visual way to explain `JOIN`: https://blog.jooq.org/2016/07/05/say-no-to-venn-diagrams-when-explaining-joins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, your query with all the subqueries is ridiculous.

```
SELECT ValueA FROM TableA 
WHERE ID = (SELECT TableA_ID FROM TableB WHERE ID = 
            (SELECT TableB_ID FROM TableC WHERE ID = 
             (SELECT TableC_ID FROM TableD WHERE ID = 1)));
```

You really need to learn to use `JOIN` if you're going to use SQL. `JOIN` is a basic operation. Avoiding `JOIN` in SQL would be like avoiding a `while` loop in most other languages.

Here's the equivalent query using JOIN syntax.

```
SELECT ValueA
FROM TableA
JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID = TableB.TableA_ID
JOIN TableC ON TableB.ID = TableC.TableB_ID
JOIN TableD ON TableC.ID = TableD.TableC_ID
WHERE TableD.ID = 1;
```

Here's a demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34503/2

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to implement this, IMHO, would be to use a join:

```
SELECT valueA
FROM   tableA
JOIN   tableB on tableB.tableA_id = tablea.id
JOIN   tableC on tableC.tableB_id = tablec.id
JOIN   tableD on tableD.tableC_id = tabled.id
WHERE  tabled.id = 1
```